# IFrame not to be reloaded on ASP.NET postback

Tags: asp.net, iframe

I have an IFrame on my asp.net page along with other user controls such as radiobutton, textbox, etc.

A problem that I am facing right now is that when I click on a radio button, it triggers the postback which make my IFrame reload as well.

Is there any way I could make the IFrame not to reload on the postback?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set AutoPostBack="false" porperty of all asp.net controls or use update panel  `<asp:RadioButton Text="text" AutoPostBack="false" runat="server" />`